# How to escape special characters in Groovy such as paranthesis and "|"?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

basically if I try oneliner in Jenkins, it often doesn't work:

`def proc = ' (echo whoami) | crontab -l '.execute()`

the problem is not the crontabl syntax even it's plain wrong, it's that `"("` and `"|"` cannot be parsed.

Comment: Show the error. And is it a Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: sorry I was able to run it by substituting with the unicode character...it's not problem with syntax overall it's jenkins bigger problem...I am running from the console in jenkins, i bet there is a simpler way to do this...

Comment: even "cd" doesn't work, can't type "cd /" even as root and cannot in any case run: "cd / && ls" - i guess the  assumptions that jenkins doesn't use terminal to be able to 'cd'. to somewhere...still no idea why the (echo ok) | whoami doesn't work...grouping should't be that hard

Comment: To use a pipe you have to run bash or sh